# Send HTML tables with SendMail

Tags: export, html

I'm trying to send some HTML table using *Mathematica* `SendMail` function. To do it I wrote this function:

```
createHTMLTable[list_List] /; Length[Dimensions@list] == 2 := 
 Module[{r, head, data}, head = First@list;
  data = Rest@list;
  head = Map["   <th>" <> ToString[#] <> "</th>\n" &, {head}, {2}];
  data = Map["   <td>" <> ToString[#] <> "</td>\n" &, data, {2}];
  headData = Join[{head}, data];
  r = "<tr>\n" <> StringJoin[##] <> "</tr>\n" & /@ headData // StringJoin;
  r = "<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <body>
                <table border=\"1\">
                    " <> r <> "
                </table>
            </body>
            </html>"
  ]
```

When I send the mail, as in this example:

```
list = RandomInteger[100000, {10, 3}]

SendMail["From" -> "test@test.com", "To" -> "test@test.com", 
 "Subject" -> "Sending Email from Mathematica", "Body" -> createHTMLTable[list], 
 "Server" -> "XXXXX"]
```

there is no table in the mail, but only the HTML text.
Anyone knows how to correct this?
Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Can you check saving `createHTMLTable[list]` to a file and then opening it with a browser ?

Comment: No.. I need it in the mail body. Today I use TableForm but Mathematica converts it into a image in the body.

Comment: I meant to check if your function produces a correct HTML file; maybe the mistake is there rather than in `SendMail`.

Comment: Ahh.. now I get. Yes, it works ok.

Comment: Could you change the Wolfram email addresses into something more innocent? We don't want to spam WRI with our test mails, do we? Also:  isn't there a `// StringJoin` too much in your code?

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries this is just the Wolfram help example. // StringJoin just put all line elements into one string.

Comment: I briefly looked at how `SendMail` works internally, and it seems that it'll always put a `text/plain` section at the beginning of the mail.  This is what most email programs will display (first).  So it might not be possible to do what you want using `SendMail` ... I might be wrong though (I can't use WorkBench yet and it's a bit difficult to read the code without syntax highlighting...)

Comment: (but it is probably possible to attach the HTML table --- this won't be displayed inline though)

Comment: I believe the problem is the MIME type is set to text/plain, so anything following will be interpreted as text.

Comment: So to solve that I would have to control MIME, that is a options that Mathematica don't let me control in SendMail. It's a pity...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using JLink and Apache Commons Email and Java Mail it is not that hard to get MIME controlling working. I just modified some code I wrote some time ago (mostly for being able to send Email from within webMathematica) and added the ability to send HTML emails. It is a whole package with the jar files in subfolder and a Notebook with an example, so I hope it is o.k. if I point interested users to my Mercurial repository here (zip download enabled):

[http://code.gluonvision.com/SendEmail/](http://code.gluonvision.com/SendEmail)

An HTML example is in SendMail.nb

Let me know if it works for you.

Rolf

Comment: Excelent! I'll try it. Just a small correction. In your SendMail.nb, you have one `"` after `To` in your example `SendMail code. And a comma is missing.

Comment: Glad it works. The type is fixed. I uploaded a new revision. That just happened when I uncommented my password ...

Comment: Unfortunately not.. I tried in Windows and Mac. I get this msg: Java::excptn: "A Java exception occurred: "org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:25\\ n \\ tat org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1242)\\ n \\ tat org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1267)\\ nCaused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. u21sm12128247yhl.6"

Comment: Did you use "PortNumber" -> 465 ?

Comment: No I have used my original google server port. Yes!.. now it works! Tks a lot! You have my point.