# How to use SendMail to send a message with URL

Tags: email

I want to send an email message containing a URL.

My first try:

```
SendMail[email, 
  {subject, "This is my <a href=\"http://www.wolfram.com\">url</a>."}]
```

My second try:

```
SendMail[email, 
  {subject, 
    Row[{"This is my ", Hyperlink["url", "http://www.wolfram.com"], "."}]}]
```

Both failed. When I am sending such messages, the message body will be attached files. Is there a work-around that can implement it? I want the message to include the hyperlink.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Send HTML tables with `SendMail`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14167/27951). In particular, the comment about `SendMail` always adding a text/plain section at the beginning of the mail which, I wonder, might be a problem if you try to include an HTML body.

Comment: @MarcoB I'm sorry,hard to understand for me.I don't know how to add that `text/plain`.Could you help to post it as an complete answer?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
SendMail[<|
  "To" -> "xyz@somewhere.com",
  "Subject" -> "Test",
  "Body" -> "Here is a link: http://www.wolfram.com.">
]
```

When I send these to myself I get an email with a working link. (I am using mail.app on a mac.)